# How to set page numbers in indesign used multiple master pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using multiple master pages and shuffle the order of master pages in document pages.

For example ...

```
page number 1 is assigned master A,
page number 2 is assigned master B,
page number 3 is assigned master c,
page number 4 is assigned master B,
page number 5 is assigned master A,
page number 6 is assigned master c,
page number 7 is assigned master D
```

How to set page numbers for the pages within the document?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean “set page number for this document”? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have created catalog design.
I have used multiple master pages and used varies pages in souffle.
now i want to set page number for my catalog.

Comment: Not certain what you mean by "souffle" - Soufflé refers to a sound which doesn't seem to be related to an InDesign document. I've edited your question a bit for clarity. If you feel my edit was unwarranted, please click the [EDIT](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/96275/edit) link under the question and correct anything I may have mistakenly changed.

Comment: @MohanRajuM Repeating the same thing again isn't going to help. “Set page number for my catalogue” does not make sense in English; I don't understand what it's supposed to mean exactly. We don't normally talk about ‘setting’ a page number. Please explain in detail what it is you want to do. Are you talking about adding page numbers to every page in the document? Or are you talking about defining how the page number should be presented? Or something else entirely?

Comment: i think what need to do is look into _sections_ – but you really need to clarify your Q.

Answer (score 2):

On each Master Page....

- Create a text frame.
- With the cursor active in the text frame, Choose `Type > Insert Special Character > Markers > Current Page Number`.
- You will see a character which corresponds to the master page in the text frame. i.e. for Master Page A, you'll see an `A`, for Master page B you'll see a `B`, etc.
- Style this character however you wish - size, font, color, etc.

These characters will *automatically* be converted to the current page number within the document when the master page is assigned to a document page. So if page 4 is using Master Page B, the character will be `4`. If page 5 is assigned Master Page A, the character will be `5`, etc.

Comment: If PickleRick's answer doesn't work for you, then you probably have some sort of setting activated in your document which tells InDesign to create a new section when you use a different master page. I don't want to complicate things unnecessarily, so I am not posting instructions about that here, but let us know if you try implementing this solution and it doesn't seem to work and we can help you continue to problem solve (if you do so, it would be really helpful for us to see a screenshot of your pages panel).